# AlarmManger setExact invoke past time alarm

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I read the developers guide about AlarmManager, but it dont speciffy the case when a setExact is set on past time.

In that case will the alram trigger (similler to set method)?

Comment: Simple enough to try out. As far as I'm aware, it behaves the same as the pre-Android r20 AlarmManager.set.

Comment: Onreceive called twice some times Ina fraction of seconds any reason?

Answer (score 0):

Well, i was running on the same question. Now I tried

```
long timeout=0;
am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeout, pendIntent);
```

and it fired instantly, so I guess the answer is YES. :)

LogCat:
06-13 13:24:42.997: V/LocationService(9729): setAlarm for Task lunch at Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 MEZ 1970